# c++ loops and boolean expressions

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm having trouble trying to do this assignment for my class for a couple of days now and would like some help.

The assignment is to write a program that informs the user of their acceptance status based on their heigh and weight qualifications depending on their gender.

At the end of the program it wants to output the number of candidates that were accepted and the average of those accepted to the overall number of candidates.

Assignment - https://www.saddleback.edu/faculty/slinker/CS1A/CS1A_Fall2013/Assignment8.pdf

We can't use switch, conditional operators, and selection (only for  outputting the correct message to the results). We can only use loops and complex boolean expressions

The problems I'm having is:

1. If all 3 of my inputs are valid, why are they not outputting if they are accepted and if one of the input (height or weight) or both were rejected then why isn't it outputting it. Is my boolean variable incorrect? If so, how do I fix it.
2. Why am i unable to exit the loop/program when I enter X. Is my while loop correct or no?
3. Is there any selection statements I can change into "not selection-statements".

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char gender;
    int  height;
    int  weight;
    bool heightOK;
    bool weightOK;
    int candidateCount;
    int validCandidateCount;
    bool invalidGender;
    bool invalidHeight;
    bool invalidWeight;
    float percentOutput;

    candidateCount = 0;
    validCandidateCount = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the candidate's information (enter 'X' to exit)."
     << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Gender: ";
        cin.get(gender);

        cin.ignore (1000,'\n');
        invalidGender = ( !(gender == 'm' ||
                            gender == 'M' ||
                            gender == 'f' ||
                            gender == 'F' ));

        candidateCount = candidateCount + 1;

        if(invalidGender)
        {
            cout << "***** Invalid gender; please enter M or F*****" <<     endl;
        }

    }while(invalidGender);

    while (gender != 'X' || gender != 'x')
    {
        candidateCount = candidateCount + 1;

        do
        {
            cout << "Height: ";
            cin  >> height;

            invalidHeight = height < 24 || height > 110;

            heightOK = ((gender == 'm' || gender == 'M') &&
                        (height > 65 && height < 80));

            heightOK = heightOK || ((gender == 'f' || gender == 'F') &&
                                    (height > 62 && height < 75));

            if(invalidHeight)
            {
                cout << "***** Invalid height; please enter a height in inches between 24 and 110. *****"
                     << endl;
            }

        }while(invalidHeight);


        do
        {
         cout << "Weight: ";
         cin  >> weight;

         invalidWeight = weight < 50 || weight > 1400;

         weightOK = ((gender == 'm' || gender == 'M') &&
                        (weight > 130 && weight < 250));

         weightOK = weightOK || ((gender == 'f' || gender == 'F') &&
                    (weight > 110 && weight < 185));

        if(invalidWeight)
            {

                cout << "***** Invalid weight; please enter a weight in lbs between 50 and 1400."
                   << endl;
            }

         }while(invalidWeight);



        if(heightOK && weightOK)
        {
            cout << "This candidate has been ACCEPTED!" << endl;

            validCandidateCount = validCandidateCount + 1;
        }
        else if (!heightOK)
        {
            cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the HEIGHT requirement."
                 << endl;
        }
        else if (!weightOK)
        {
            cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the WEIGHT requirement."
                 << endl;
        }
        else if (!(heightOK && weightOK))
        {
            cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the HEIGHT and WEIGHT requirements"
                 << endl;
        }
        do
        {
            cout << "Gender: ";
            cin.get(gender);
            cin.ignore (1000,'\n');

            candidateCount = candidateCount + 1;

            if(invalidGender)
            {
            cout << "***** Invalid gender; please enter M or F*****" <<        endl;  
            }
        }while(invalidGender);


    }

    cout << validCandidateCount << " candidate(s) accepted!" << endl;

    percentOutput = validCandidateCount / candidateCount;

    cout << "That's " << percentOutput <<"%!" << endl;



return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've got some bad news. In addition to any bugs, your keyboard appears to be broken. The TAB key doesn't work right. As a result, the shown code lacks logical, meaningful indentation, and is mostly unreadable. You need to get your keyboard fixed. After all, if you're asking for others to help figure out your programming issues, the very least you could do is expend a little bit of effort to make your code as easy to read, and follow, as possible by using logical indentation. If you don't even bother to indent your code correctly, why should anyone would want to help you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik 

Is it fixed now? Didn't realize you can't use tab when posting. So I just did 4 spaces.

Comment: Where have you declared `invalidGender`? When I run your code, the compiler gives me the error: `||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
||In function 'int main()':||31|error: 'invalidGender' was not declared in this scope||42|error: 'invalidGender' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|`
`

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer

sorry I just edited it in, somehow when i copy and pasted my code, it didn't bring it in. it should be fixed now

Comment: This seems to be more of a logic error. I would recommend that you toy around a bit with your logic; try each do-while statement individually to see if it provides what you want/expect it to provide. Hopefully, you have some time left before its due ;)

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer

Ok, yeah I have a couple of a days before its due. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main while loop should have and condition.

```
while(gender !='X' && gender!='x)
```

And your selection code has wrong conditional statements.

```
   if(heightOK && weightOK)
    {
        cout << "This candidate has been ACCEPTED!" << endl;

        validCandidateCount = validCandidateCount + 1;
    }
    else if (!heightOK) // you have written else if(heightOK)
    {
        cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the HEIGHT requirement."
             << endl;
    }
    else if (!weightOK)  // you have written else if(weightOK)
    {
        cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the WEIGHT requirement."
             << endl;
    }
    else if (!(heightOK && weightOK))
    {
        cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the HEIGHT and WEIGHT requirements"
             << endl;
    }
```

You should remove that invalidgender condition in the last do while loop, otherwise it will cause an infinite loop even if you wish to exit by pressing X.
Instead the invalid gender condition can be placed at the starting of main While loop.

And invalidGender variable should be assigned its value again otherwise it will pick up the previously stored value.

```
  invalidGender = ( !(gender == 'm' ||
                        gender == 'M' ||
                        gender == 'f' ||
                        gender == 'F' ));
```

the whole code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char gender;
int  height;
int  weight;
bool heightOK;
bool weightOK;
int candidateCount;
int validCandidateCount;
bool invalidGender;
bool invalidHeight;
bool invalidWeight;
double percentOutput;

candidateCount = 0;
validCandidateCount = 0;

cout << "Please enter the candidate's information (enter 'X' to exit)."
 << endl;

  cout << "Gender: ";
  cin.get(gender);

while (gender != 'X' && gender != 'x')
{
    candidateCount = candidateCount + 1;

    do
    {
        invalidGender = ( !(gender == 'm' ||
                        gender == 'M' ||
                        gender == 'f' ||
                        gender == 'F' ));

        if(invalidGender)
        {
           cout << "***** Invalid gender; please enter M or F*****" <<        endl;  
           cout << "Gender: ";
           cin>>gender;
           cin.ignore (1000,'\n');
        }
    }while(invalidGender);

    do
    {
        cout << "Height: ";
        cin  >> height;

        invalidHeight = height < 24 || height > 110;

        heightOK = ((gender == 'm' || gender == 'M') &&
                    (height > 65 && height < 80));

        heightOK = heightOK || ((gender == 'f' || gender == 'F') &&
                                (height > 62 && height < 75));

        if(invalidHeight)
        {
            cout << "***** Invalid height; please enter a height in inches between 24 and 110. *****"
                 << endl;
        }

    }while(invalidHeight);


    do
    {
     cout << "Weight: ";
     cin  >> weight;

     invalidWeight = weight < 50 || weight > 1400;

     weightOK = ((gender == 'm' || gender == 'M') &&
                    (weight > 130 && weight < 250));

     weightOK = weightOK || ((gender == 'f' || gender == 'F') &&
                (weight > 110 && weight < 185));

    if(invalidWeight)
        {

            cout << "***** Invalid weight; please enter a weight in lbs between 50 and 1400."
               << endl;
        }

     }while(invalidWeight);



    if(heightOK && weightOK)
    {
        cout << "This candidate has been ACCEPTED!" << endl;

        validCandidateCount = validCandidateCount + 1;
    }
    else if (!heightOK)
    {
        cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the HEIGHT requirement."
             << endl;
    }
    else if (!weightOK)
    {
        cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the WEIGHT requirement."
             << endl;
    }
    else if (!(heightOK && weightOK))
    {
        cout << "This candidate has been rejected based on the HEIGHT and WEIGHT requirements"
             << endl;
    }


        cout << "Gender: ";
        cin>>gender;
        cin.ignore (1000,'\n');

}

cout << validCandidateCount << " candidate(s) accepted!" << endl;

percentOutput = (double)validCandidateCount / (double)candidateCount;

cout << "That's " << percentOutput*100 <<"%!" << endl;



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Chandini, thanks for responding. I added the invalidGender variable assignment again in the 2nd gender input(last do-while) but I don't understand where I should put the invalid gender condition from the last do while to the main while.

Comment: If I remove the invalid condition in the last do while, what do i add instead? cuz I can't leave the while condition in the do while blank. And how do i add it to the start of the main while loop?

Comment: Okay, I did that but now my program ends after I put a valid input for gender

Comment: Just before the do while loop of Height add 
do
        {
            if(invalidGender)
            {
            cout << "***** Invalid gender; please enter M or F*****" <<                endl;  
          cout << "Gender: ";
            cin.get(gender);
            cin.ignore (1000,'\n');  }
        }while(invalidGender);

Comment: Thanks that works but for the removing the invalid condition. How do I do that? I can't leave the do while condition blank or it gives me an syntax error. Like you said, it does an infinite loop and inputting X does not exit me out.

Comment: Also, when it first does the inputs it works fine but after the first time, whatever I put an valid gender input, it would show it as invalid but it fixes itself the 2nd time it asks for input gender. How do I fix this?

Comment: Thank you so much Chandini. I saw that you fixed the percentOutput as well. Only problem I have left is that if both heightOK and weightOK are not true then it would only output the height being invalid but not both. So Im assuming that since the else if statement for heightOK is true then it skips the rest?

For example, if both the weight and height are rejected inputs, I want it to output "This candidate has been rejected based on the HEIGHT and WEIGHT requirements" but it only outputs "This candidate has been rejected based on the HEIGHT requirement.

Answer (score -1):

The Boolean data types need to be declared true or false. And this needs to be set before iterations.

Also:

The program needs to run before a user can input x to quit.

std:string QUIT;

QUIT = “XXX”;

Then use selection structure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33869936)